# What's the flag weight formula in the 500-750 range?

Tags: discussion, flag-weight

We've been told the flag weight formula above 500 has an asymptote of 750. What exactly is the formula being used though?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached/84569#84569

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because flag weight has been removed from the system for many years now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure the *exact* formula is particularly helpful, but the *usual* increase (10, 5, whatever) is multiplied by the exponent (of 10) of some negative number, calculated as the difference between your current weight and 500, along with some scaling factor. Such that *at 500* you get full points (10^0 == 1), with that dropping fairly swiftly after that.

There is nothing *particularly* scientific about that, other than it gives the shape we were looking for. I can recall that it would take 1072 correct flags *with none incorrect* to get to something like 749.5. But getting 700+ is sooner (you flagging-crazy fiends know who you are!).

"How much to reach x" is probably unanswerable except with "from y, assuming no flags get bounced". Re % (comments); that isn't something we can directly report at the moment.

Since computers do lots of rounding, for all I know it *might* be possible to hit 750.00; but there is a hard max - even if the maths goes wobbly through rounding error, you cannot exceed 750.

Comment: Oh, "how much to reach x" also depends on which types of flags

Comment: @Richard - that would probably not be well received. I recommend against it.

Comment: @Richard - I mean: well-received by maths.SE - that isn't the type of question they crave

Comment: *you flagging-crazy fiends know who you are!* - Are you suggesting that level of flagging is frowned upon? Yes, my flag weight is >700.

Comment: @marcog the exact opposite; they are good and correct flags, and do nothing but improve the site. Bring it on!

Comment: @Marc Good to know :)

Answer (score 3):

It is not super-linear, it is asymptotic

> @Mehrdad - asymptotic, but not logarithmic – Marc Gravell♦ Mar 10 at 7:27

Under this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight/80178#80178

The formula is.. well, to be a true asymptote, it must use something like TAN() or an inverted (1/x) series. Plug your own numbers and you can't go far from the truth.

**You will never reach 750**, for that is the definition of [Asymptote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote)

---

## EDIT

Except.. when it is **not** and asymptote.  See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached/88856#88856
It appears flag weight ***ALWAYS*** goes up by at least 0.1, right up to 750.

Comment: Got the wrong terminology, removed super-linear from the question (still the same question). I want to know how many valid flags I need to reach a flag weight of X, as well as have a sense of what percentage of my flags are being marked valid/invalid.

Comment: Computers do rounding; on a computer you probably *can* reach it... eventually.

Comment: @Marc: Sorry to keep nagging, but this has [nothing to do with rounding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached/84569#84569).