# My Flag weight fluctuates even with no changes

Tags: discussion, support, flag-weight

Earlier today, before I had flagged anything, my flag weight was 637 (and change). After the admins had checked all my flags, they went up to 648 (and change). And now (I haven't flagged anything else), it's down to 628 (and change).

What causes the flag weight to drop so precipitously when nothing has changed? Is this a bug?

#### Update

MMyers points out that I had two flags marked `Invalid` today, out of the 16 I had cast.  *Two* invalid flags take out a lot more than 14 valid flags give. <strike>Does anyone have a link to the formula used by Stack Exchange to measure flag weight?</strike>

**Edit**: It appears that the formula (after a fashion) is [available here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83530/whats-the-flag-weight-formula-in-the-500-750-range).

Comment: Windy days can causes flags to fluctuate.

Comment: FLAG WEIGHTS!  Slowly I turned... Step, by step.  Inch by inch...

Comment: Remember that flags on comments also affect flag weight, even though they're not shown in your "invalid" flag totals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see two invalid flags for you today, so I'm guessing that not all your flags had actually been checked when you were at 648.

Comment: So two invalid flags wipe out the 'weight' earned by 14 valid flags? Not just wipe it, but take it *even lower* than it was before?

Comment: @George: correct.

Comment: @George Stocker: For reference, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bflag-weight%5D+unfair